# Using python to find Cisco IOS interfaces with a specific config

Tags: python, regex, cisco

I have hundreds of cisco configuration files and I need to find (via python) the interfaces with a specific service policy applied in this case WIRELESS-IN.

This is the regex I used to capture the interface:

```py
pat=re.compile('(interface.*?)!$',re.DOTALL|re.M)
```

That should return "FastEthernet1/0/2".

My regex classifies interface elements into a list of lines, but how should I search for WIRELESS-IN within the list of lines?

Example configuration:

```
interface FastEthernet1/0/1
 description Foo
 switchport access vlan 300
 switchport mode access
 switchport port-security aging time 2
 no logging event link-status
 speed 100
 duplex full
 priority-queue out
 mls qos trust dscp
 no snmp trap link-status
 no cdp enable
 spanning-tree portfast
 hold-queue 120 in
 hold-queue 200 out
 ip dhcp snooping trust
!
interface FastEthernet1/0/2
 description wlap2
 switchport access vlan 100
 switchport mode access
 switchport port-security maximum 15
 switchport port-security
 switchport port-security aging time 2
 switchport port-security aging type inactivity
 ip access-group 100 in
 no logging event link-status
 srr-queue bandwidth shape 0 0 0 10
 queue-set 2
 priority-queue out
 no snmp trap link-status
 storm-control broadcast level pps 100 50
 storm-control multicast level pps 100 50
 storm-control action trap
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
 service-policy input WIRELESS_IN
 ip dhcp snooping limit rate 15
!
interface FastEthernet1/0/3
 description Test3
 switchport access vlan 199
 switchport mode access
 switchport port-security aging time 2
 no logging event link-status
 queue-set 2
 priority-queue out
 mls qos trust dscp
 no snmp trap link-status
 no cdp enable
 spanning-tree portfast
 service-policy input VOICE-LAN
```

This is what I tried using:

```
import re,string
f = open("sampleconfig.cfg")
cfgdata = f.read()
pat=re.compile('(interface.*?)!$',re.DOTALL|re.M)
pat2 = re.compile("service-policy.input.WIRELESS-IN")

data = pat.findall(cfgdata)
i=0
while i < len(data):
    if  pat2.findall(data[i]):
        print (data[i].split("\n")[0])
        i = i+1

    else:
        i = i+1
        pass
```

Comment: You should put the regex you're using in your question.

Comment: What do you want to search for within that group?

Comment: I wanted to return just the Interface line for lines matching the identified service policy. I built something that works, but there's probably a better way!

Comment: it's worth pointing out that your Cisco IOS config uses `WIRELESS_IN` but your script looks for `WIRELESS-IN`

Answer (score 9):

> I have hundreds of cisco configuration files and I need to find (via python) the interfaces with a specific service policy applied in this case WIRELESS-IN. The Regex I am using to capture the interface is: pat=re.compile('(interface.*?)!$',re.DOTALL|re.M)
>   ...
>
> I'd need to return `FastEthernet1/0/2` in this case.

#### Answer:

You should use [ciscoconfparse](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ciscoconfparse)<sup>1</sup>... assume I stored your configuration in a file called `stackoverflow_question.conf`...

```py
>>> from ciscoconfparse import CiscoConfParse
>>> parse = CiscoConfParse('stackoverflow_question.conf')
>>> # .find_parents_w_child() returns a list of matching parent conf lines
>>> wifi_qos_intfs = parse.find_parents_w_child('^interface', 'WIRELESS_IN')
>>> print(wifi_qos_intfs)
['interface FastEthernet1/0/2']
>>>
```

#### How it works

[ciscoconfparse](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ciscoconfparse)'s API is fairly simple; it breaks the Cisco configuration into parents / children.  `service-policy input WIRELESS_IN` is considered a child of `interface FastEthernet1/0/2`.

When you call `CiscoConfParse(configuration_file)`, [ciscoconfparse](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ciscoconfparse) builds relationships to Cisco IOS config lines as parent and child statements; an object with all those relationships is returned.  Then `parse.find_parents_w_child(parentstr, childstr)`, is a method on the aforementioned object, which walks the configuration and returns a list of text lines which match `parentstr`, and have one or more children matching `childstr`.

I used a regex like `^interface` to guarantee that `parentstr` only matches Cisco IOS interface lines. and not other statements that might also use the word `interface` in them.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Full-disclosure: I am [ciscoconfparse](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ciscoconfparse)'s author.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Whether that's a better way is open to dispute, but it's at least somewhat different:

```
import re,string
f = open("sampleconfig.cfg")
cfgdata = f.read()
pat = '(?sm)interface (\S*)(?:(?!^!$).)*service-policy.input.WIRELESS_IN.*?!$'
data = re.findall(pat, cfgdata)
```

Comment: This is a fantastic piece of regex. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Another way how this task can be addressed is to use [TTP](https://github.com/dmulyalin/ttp) module (which I am the author of) with match results filtering, for instance this code:

```
my_template="""
<group 
name="interfaces_with_WIRELESS-IN_policy.{{ interface }}" functions="contains(policy)">
interface {{ interface }}
 service-policy input {{ policy | equal(WIRELESS_IN) }}
</group>
"""

from ttp import ttp
parser = ttp(template=my_template)
parser.parse()
print(parser.result(format="json")[0])
```

will produce this results:

```
[
    {
        "interfaces_with_WIRELESS-IN_policy": {
            "FastEthernet1/0/2": {
                "policy": "WIRELESS_IN"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

**How it works**

TTP parses text data that OP provided to extract interfaces and policies attached to them, without any filtering these results would be produced:

```
[
    {
        "interfaces_with_WIRELESS-IN_policy": {
            "FastEthernet1/0/1": {},
            "FastEthernet1/0/2": {
                "policy": "WIRELESS_IN"
            },
            "FastEthernet1/0/3": {
                "policy": "VOICE-LAN"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

but by using match variable function "equal" we can instruct TTP to invalidate match results that are not equal to "WIRELESS_IN", in addition, after defining functions="contains(policy)" for group, TTP will check if group results (which are python dictionary) have key named "policy", invalidating group match results without such a key.

However, above code will not produce list of interfaces (as requested by OP) until you apply one more TTP groups function - "itemize" - which will create a list of items out of group results, e.g. template:

```
my_template="""
<group 
name="interfaces_with_WIRELESS-IN_policy" functions="contains(policy) | itemize(interface)">
interface {{ interface }}
 service-policy input {{ policy | equal(WIRELESS_IN) }}
</group>
"""
```

will emit these results:

```
[
    {
        "interfaces_with_WIRELESS-IN_policy": [
            "FastEthernet1/0/2"
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import re,string
f = open("sampleconfig.cfg")
cfgdata = f.read()
pat=re.compile('(interface.*?)!$',re.DOTALL|re.M)
pat2 = re.compile("service-policy.input.WIRELESS-IN")

data = pat.findall(cfgdata)
i=0
while i < len(data):
    if  pat2.findall(data[i]):
        print (data[i].split("\n")[0])
        i = i+1

    else:
        i = i+1
        pass
```